# CAS service ticket validate failed

Tags: ssl, service, single-sign-on, cas

I have followed a link http://lukesampson.com/post/315838839/cas-on-windows-localhost-setup-in-5-mins,  then the cas server works correctly, the login url is http://10.1.1.26:8080/login, the validate url is http://10.1.1.26:8080/serviceValidate.

Then I tested it like below:

1. call http://10.1.1.26:8080/login?service=http://10.1.1.9:8081/default.aspx
2. I get the service ticket successfully, such as ST-9-pJ5UDxqKIHP2zuN3JGe4-cas
3. then I validate the service ticket by calling http://10.1.1.26:8080/serviceValidate?ticket=ST-9-pJ5UDxqKIHP2zuN3JGe4-cas&service=http://10.1.1.9:8081/default.aspx,
4. unfortunately, it always return invalid ticket,

in order to fix it, I try cas 1.0 validate url, http://10.1.1.26:8080/validate?ticket=ST-9-pJ5UDxqKIHP2zuN3JGe4-cas&service=http://10.1.1.9:8081/default.aspx, but it return "no".

Then I generate a certificate file and put it into keystore, then I tried all the above steps by using https://10.1.1.26:8443, howevery, the validation was still failed.

I changed the cas log4j configuration, to print all debug information, and below is the log

```
2012-02-21 13:18:36,371 DEBUG [org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet
] - <DispatcherServlet with name 'cas' processing GET request for [/cas-server-w
ebapp-3.4.11/serviceValidate]>
2012-02-21 13:18:36,381 DEBUG [org.springframework.webflow.mvc.servlet.FlowHandl
erMapping] - <No flow mapping found for request with URI '/cas-server-webapp-3.4
.11/serviceValidate'>
2012-02-21 13:18:36,381 DEBUG [org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.SimpleUrl
HandlerMapping] - <Mapping [/serviceValidate] to HandlerExecutionChain with hand
ler [org.jasig.cas.web.ServiceValidateController@302a4b] and 1 interceptor>
2012-02-21 13:18:36,381 DEBUG [org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet
] - <Last-Modified value for [/cas-server-webapp-3.4.11/serviceValidate] is: -1>
2012-02-21 13:18:36,391 INFO [org.jasig.cas.CentralAuthenticationServiceImpl] -
<ServiceTicket [ST-1-pqIeCRqcafGBE6idoCcd-cas] has expired.>
2012-02-21 13:18:36,391 INFO [com.github.inspektr.audit.support.Slf4jLoggingAudi
tTrailManager] - <Audit trail record BEGIN
=============================================================
WHO: audit:unknown
WHAT: ST-1-pqIeCRqcafGBE6idoCcd-cas
ACTION: SERVICE_TICKET_VALIDATE_FAILED
APPLICATION: CAS
WHEN: Tue Feb 21 13:18:36 EST 2012
CLIENT IP ADDRESS: 10.1.1.9
SERVER IP ADDRESS: 10.1.1.26
=============================================================
```

What I don't understand and don't know why is from other post I saw log has something like " write service ticket to ticket registry, and retrieve service ticket ", but there is nothing about that in my log

Answer (score 19, accepted):

I'm not 100% sure because I can't see your configuration, but the log says this

```
<ServiceTicket [ST-1-pqIeCRqcafGBE6idoCcd-cas] has expired.>
```

Which means that the ticket has already expired. There exists a config-file in CAS called `ticketExpirationPolicies.xml` which contains the times a ticket is valid. In my CAS-version the expiration period for a service ticket is set to 10000ms. Maybe the time between you step 1 and 3 is longer than the expiration setting in your file (of course) which could differ from mine

```
<!-- Expiration policies -->
<bean id="serviceTicketExpirationPolicy" class="org.jasig.cas.ticket.support.MultiTimeUseOrTimeoutExpirationPolicy">
    <!-- This argument is the number of times that a ticket can be used before its considered expired. -->
    <constructor-arg
        index="0"
        value="1" />
    
    <!-- This argument is the time a ticket can exist before its considered expired.  -->
    <constructor-arg
        index="1"
        value="10000" />
</bean>

<bean id="grantingTicketExpirationPolicy" class="org.jasig.cas.ticket.support.TimeoutExpirationPolicy">
    <!-- This argument is the time a ticket can exist before its considered expired.  -->
    <constructor-arg
        index="0"
        value="7200000" />
</bean>
```

The tutorial that you follow in my opinion is not complete in its configuration settings. Depending on what you try to achieve with this CAS-server you could need some of the customization described [here](http://hantri.blogspot.com/search/label/CAS)

Comment: Same problems as here, apparently the default expiration time is very short. I changed and it worked.

Answer (score 0):

Look the date of your servers, in my case I had 10 seconds of difference between HA servers and I received ticket expired.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/31334409)