# Central Authentication Server architecture and authentication flow

Tags: java, cas

Recently while I was working with CAS server,got a conceptual problem... As I understood as soon as a ticket validation succeeds, that ticket get erased... But why ? And where exactly the user role is checked at ?

Thanx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By default the ServiceTicket(ST) can be used only once and for a short time only(Its bound to a `MultiTimeUseOrTimeoutExpirationPolicy`). This is like Mike said ins his answer to ensure that it is not misused. This pre-settings can be changed if you really need to as I wrote already on [another post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9371316/cas-service-ticket-validate-failed/9411397#9411397) by changing the `ticketExpirationPolicy.xml` file

However the TicketGrantingTicket(TGT) remains active and is by default only bound to a `TimeoutExpirationPolicy` and not limited by the amount of request. From the TGT the CAS can create as many STs as you need.

Answer (score 0):

CAS service tickets are one-time use to eliminate the risk of a replay attack.  If you use the recommended setup, your client should only talk to CAS server over HTTPS, so when a service ticket is obtained from CAS server, it remains confidential.  However a ticket could then potentially be presented by the client to the desired service on an unencrypted channel (i.e. HTTP).  Therefore, it's no longer safe to assume it is secret after its first use.  Furthermore, one use is all that's necessary to authenticate the client, so allowing additional uses after that doesn't make much sense.  It's just asking for trouble.

When it comes to user roles, that's up to your application.  CAS's purpose is to tell you who you are dealing with (authentication), and it does that well.  What a particular user is allowed to do in your application (authorization) is a different problem and not the one CAS is intended to solve.