# CAS ticket validation always fails

Tags: spring-security, single-sign-on, cas

I installed CAS 4.1 successfully and configured it to use Active Directory as backend authentication. Now the problem is, that each time I try to validate a ticket CAS server complains about the ticket has expired. The steps i've been doing to get and validate a ticket are as follow:

1. call https://sso.domain.net/cas/login?service=https://myservice.domain.net
2. I get a ticket such ST-2-NLOngMHayTl3uCLKn91T-sso.domain.net
3. Call validation service https://sso.domain.net/serviceValidate?ticket=ST-3-zrjAFf1UU95NdzGmCibv-sso.domain.net&service=https://myservice.domain.net

And I get the following response:

```
<cas:serviceResponse xmlns:cas="http://www.yale.edu/tp/cas">
  <script/>
  <cas:authenticationFailure code="INVALID_TICKET"> 
   Ticket 'ST-3-zrjAFf1UU95NdzGmCibv-sso.domain.net' not recognized
  </cas:authenticationFailure>
</cas:serviceResponse>
```

Ticket granting log shows

```
2015-12-18 15:28:53,505 INFO [org.jasig.cas.CentralAuthenticationServiceImpl] - <Granted ticket [ST-3-zrjAFf1UU95NdzGmCibv-sso.domain.net] for service [https://e.domain.net/] for user [castest]>
2015-12-18 15:28:53,506 INFO  [org.jasig.inspektr.audit.support.Slf4jLoggingAuditTrailManager] - <Audit trail record BEGIN
Dec 18 15:28:53 mk-jas-cas-01 server[24501]:    =============================================================
Dec 18 15:28:53 mk-jas-cas-01 server[24501]: WHO: castest
Dec 18 15:28:53 mk-jas-cas-01 server[24501]: WHAT: ST-3-zrjAFf1UU95NdzGmCibv-sso.domain.net for https://e.domain.net/
Dec 18 15:28:53 mk-jas-cas-01 server[24501]: ACTION: SERVICE_TICKET_CREATED
Dec 18 15:28:53 mk-jas-cas-01 server[24501]: APPLICATION: CAS
Dec 18 15:28:53 mk-jas-cas-01 server[24501]: WHEN: Fri Dec 18 15:28:53 AST 2015
Dec 18 15:28:53 mk-jas-cas-01 server[24501]: CLIENT IP ADDRESS: 10.100.25.89
Dec 18 15:28:53 mk-jas-cas-01 server[24501]: SERVER IP ADDRESS: 10.10.12.120
Dec 18 15:28:53 mk-jas-cas-01 server[24501]: =============================================================
```

The validation log shows

```
2015-12-18 15:29:05,633 INFO [org.jasig.cas.CentralAuthenticationServiceImpl] - <ServiceTicket [ST-3-zrjAFf1UU95NdzGmCibv-sso.domain.net] has expired.>
Dec 18 15:29:05 mk-jas-cas-01 server[24501]: 2015-12-18 15:29:05,635 INFO [org.jasig.inspektr.audit.support.Slf4jLoggingAuditTrailManager] - <Audit trail record BEGIN
Dec 18 15:29:05 mk-jas-cas-01 server[24501]: =============================================================
Dec 18 15:29:05 mk-jas-cas-01 server[24501]: WHO: audit:unknown
Dec 18 15:29:05 mk-jas-cas-01 server[24501]: WHAT: ST-3-zrjAFf1UU95NdzGmCibv-sso.domain.net
Dec 18 15:29:05 mk-jas-cas-01 server[24501]: ACTION: SERVICE_TICKET_VALIDATE_FAILED
Dec 18 15:29:05 mk-jas-cas-01 server[24501]: APPLICATION: CAS
Dec 18 15:29:05 mk-jas-cas-01 server[24501]: WHEN: Fri Dec 18 15:29:05 AST 2015
Dec 18 15:29:05 mk-jas-cas-01 server[24501]: CLIENT IP ADDRESS: 10.100.25.89
Dec 18 15:29:05 mk-jas-cas-01 server[24501]: SERVER IP ADDRESS: 10.10.12.120
Dec 18 15:29:05 mk-jas-cas-01 server[24501]:=============================================================
```

I used the same ticketExpirationPolicy.xml from this [StackOverflow entry](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9371316/cas-service-ticket-validate-failed)
and I got the same result, I tried also changing to no expiration at all but get the same result
My current ticketExpirationPolicy.xml file:

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
   xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
   xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p"
   xmlns:c="http://www.springframework.org/schema/c" xmlns:util="http://www.springframework.org/schema/util"
   xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
                       http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
                       http://www.springframework.org/schema/util
                       http://www.springframework.org/schema/util/spring-util.xsd">

<bean id="serviceTicketExpirationPolicy" class="org.jasig.cas.ticket.support.MultiTimeUseOrTimeoutExpirationPolicy">
    <!-- This argument is the number of times that a ticket can be used before its considered expired. -->
    <constructor-arg
        index="0"
        value="1" />
    <!-- This argument is the time a ticket can exist before its considered expired.  -->
    <constructor-arg
        index="1"
        value="10000" />
</bean>
<bean id="grantingTicketExpirationPolicy" class="org.jasig.cas.ticket.support.NeverExpiresExpirationPolicy" />
</beans>
```

A side question: where and how do I define a service to act as a proxy?!

Answer (score 1):

Well, I fixed it by increasing the second constructor argument from 10000 to 100000

```
<!-- This argument is the time a ticket can exist before its considered expired.  -->
<constructor-arg
    index="1"
    value="100000" />
```

Comment: Increasing this value worked for me too. But, I would like to keep the shortest acceptable window possible for expiry so, I might try an whittle down that value. Surprisingly, I could see other applications access CAS with the default value just being 10,000. Assuming that this represents 10 secs. I now have 100 secs on the plate for that service ticket to be invalidated by expiry which was happening to my service BUT not to another service !!